# Turning Off Publishing Content Approval for Editing Pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow, publishing, content-approval

I have a SharePoint 2013 Publishing site Intranet using a single site collection. I have turned off the Publishing Approval Workflow in site settings (root site collection) and this did not work - approval emails still being sent out.

The following Microsoft documentation is incorrect (Step 6: no workflows appear):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/all-about-approval-workflows-HA102771433.aspx#DisableRemove

I also have a handful of team sites and do not want these affected. Surely, there is a straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to go into every page / image / doc library - Settings, Versioning settings and set content approval to no.